# RAILS Auto refresh partial

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, refresh

I have a controller events with action show :

```
  def show
    @event = Event.get(params[:id])

    if !connected? || !@event 
      return redirect_to request.referrer || root_path
    end

    @requests = @event.get_requests
  end
```

In view **show.html.erb** i have

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(
     function() {
      setInterval(function() {
        $('#requests').load('/events/reload_requests');
    }, 2000);
  });
</script>
...
<div class="party-block" id="requests">
    <%= render partial: 'requests' %>
</div>
...
```

The javascript function call controller method **events/reload_requests** :

```
def reload_requests
  @requests = @event.get_requests
  render partial: 'events/requests'
end
```

And content of partial **_requests.html.erb** :

```
<%= Time.now %>
<h4><%= t '.requests' %></h4>
<% @requests.each do |r| %>
 <span class="request">
 ...
<% end %>
```

Problem : The javascript function load all the content of my **show.html.erb** page in div **#requests**, but in the copy of **show.html.erb** in the div, it refresh div #request correctly :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEBZi.jpg)
You can see, in show#requests i have the content of show.
Than you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly but you are calling `render partial: 'events/requests` from `show.html.erb` and `render partial: 'requests'` within `_requests.html.erb` would specifying the full path `'events/requests'` in your `_requests.html.erb` file fix your problem?

Comment: Sorry i dont understand. I have to change render partial: 'requests' to render partial: 'events/requests' in action reload_requests ?

Comment: yes, that is what I suggested

Comment: Doesn't work, i have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-reading your question, I think I understood your problem.

When you call the `#load` method, the HTML returned is actually your whole `show.html.erb` template.. which gets inserted into your `$('#requests')` element. Is that correct?

In the jQuery docs, you can find the following at: http://api.jquery.com/load/

> Loading Page Fragments
>
> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. (...)
>
> $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #fragment" );

Maybe if you modify your script tag as follow:

```
<script>
  ...
        $('#requests').load('/events/reload_requests #requests');
  ...
</script>
```

you can insert only the fragment of the HTML you are interested in.

Please let me know if that was not your question.

Also, if your request to `'event/reload_requests'` is returning your `show.html.erb` template, you may be mistakenly routing the `event/reload_requests` endpoint to your `#show` action.

Edit#1

The cleanest way to fix the nested div problem seems to be to add a container div and load from there:

```
$('#requestsContainer').load('/events/reload_requests #requests');
```

html:

```
<div id="requestsContainer">
  <div class="party-block" id="requests">
      <%= render partial: 'requests' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's work but i have a div into my div                                                        `<div id="requests" class="party-block">
<div id="requests" class="party-block">...
</div>`

Comment: And reload_requests is a private method in controller events

Comment: see Edit#1 about the nested div problem.

Comment: if `#reload_requests` is a private method, what controller action is your `/events/reload_requests` endpoint routing to?

Comment: Fixed, just need to reload server

Comment: this seems like another set of problems though.. you should open the network tab in your developer tools or your rails server console and try to see where the requests are failing.

Comment: Always good to restart the server ;) -- Please open another issue if you encounter other problems.

Comment: Thank you a lot, and sorry for my very bad english, i'm french student ;D

Comment: No worries, I understood in the end ;) -- Also, it would be great if you could accept the answer as the solution if it's ok.

Comment: It's OK ? Sorry i cant vote because my reputation < 15

Comment: Sorry just i dont't understant one thing. You say **Also, if your request to 'event/reload_requests' is returning your show.html.erb template**, but in the action reload_requests, i precise **render partial: 'events/requests'**

Comment: That's also what I didn't understand. Your request to `'event/reload_requests'` should return only the content of the `_requests.html.erb` partial, but you said that it returns `show.html.erb`.

You said, `The javascript function load all the content of my show.html.erb page in div #requests`. which means, your call to `event/reload_requests` is rendering your `show.html.erb` template rather than your `_requests.html.erb`... Is that possible?

Comment: I dont Know why... You can see my code, i render a partial but it render all my file show

Comment: please edit your question and add the content of your `config/routes.rb` file